# lower bound on $\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{n}{i}$ for $k<n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Given two positive numbers $n,k$ s.t. $k<n$, an upper bound for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}\binom{n}{i}$ is $\frac{2n^k}{k!}$. Are there any known lower bounds as well? (in particular when $k=2^x-1$ and $n=x2^{x-1}$ for positive integer $x$).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\binom{n}{k} \geq \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^k$ for $k > 0$.

Then, $$\sum_{i = 0}^k \binom{n}{i} \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{n}{i}\right)^i \geq \sum_{i=0}^k \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^i = \frac{\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^{k+1} - 1}{\frac{n}{k} - 1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The sum is the volume of a Hamming sphere in the $n$ dimensional hypercube. Together with Stirling approximation, this will essentially yield the lower bound $2^{n H((k+1)/n)}$ where $H(p)$ is binary Shannon entropy and for your choice of $n,k$ will probably be quite good.

Comment: Interesting. I assume $k\leq n/2$ for which the *upper bound* $\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{n}{i}\leq 2^{nH(k/n)}$ exists. Not sure if this is different from what you are saying.

Comment: yes its the same idea.